# Connect with Router to another Wi-Fi AP

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection, wireless-access-point

How can i connect with my Desktop PC that connected to a Wi-Fi Router, to another wireless AP (Access Point) like a Shared Wireless Network that shared from a Laptop ? (My Router Model: TP-Link TD-W8961ND)

Answer (score 0):

- [MyPublicWiFi](http://www.mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/en/index.html) : Turn your computer into a WiFi Access Point with Firewall and URL Tracking
  [image]

Comment: I don't want to be a AP ! I Just want to connect them :)

Comment: Do you mean that you wish your router connecting to AP

Comment: Yep ! I Want to connect my router to another AccessPoint

Comment: Try with bridge http://www.tp-link.com/gr/article/?faqid=327

Comment: ,So what if the second Wireless router doesn't like my Router for example; another Shared Network that shared from a Laptop !

Comment: They cant do anything really only kick your router out you could try to spoof a mac address but its to advanced and i dont think your router supports it. I would recommend to buy a wireless repeater. example => http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/D-LINK-DIR-615-WIRELESS-N-ROUTER-REPEATER-BRIDGE-WITH-DD-WRT-CUSTOM-FIRMWARE-/290939896380?pt=UK_Computing_Wireless_Routers&hash=item43bd5e823c